# How to import and use functions from .dll to VB.NET? I have solution for this in VBA, but not for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vba, dll, interop, dllimport

I'm newbie in VB.NET. I have some application I have writed in VBA, and now want to transfer to VB.NET.
There is example how I'm declaring these .dll functions:

```vba
Public Declare Function loadsession Lib "vpmsdl32" (ByVal vpmname As String) As Long
Public Declare Function setvar Lib "vpmsdl32.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal fieldname As String, ByVal value As String) As Long
Public Declare Function compute Lib "vpmsdl32.dll" (ByVal session As Long, ByVal what As String, ByVal result As String, ByVal result_buffer_size As Long, ByVal message As String, ByVal message_buffer_size As Long, ByVal fieldref As String, ByVal fieldref_buffer_size As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function closesession Lib "vpmsdl32.dll" (ByVal session As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function unloadall Lib "vpmsdl32" () As Long
```

I'm using this in VBA code in the way, for example, when I open the session with function loadsession:

```vba
session = loadsession("absolute-path-to-the-file")
```

set the input parameters:

```vba
ret = setvar(session, "Input name", "Input value")
```

(Hint: I don't have to declare variable `ret`) after that I perform computing with:

```vba
retcomp = compute(session, "Output name", result, 4000, msg, 1000, fieldref, 250)
```

(Hint: I also don't have to declare variable `retcomp`) After that, I get result of calculation in the variable `result` (It is not clear for me how it is possible to use variable for calling the function as output variable, for some reasons this function assign result of the computation to variable `result`, but it works!)

Now, I'm trying to implement the similar way in VB.NET application. First, I perform `DLLImport of these functions`:

```vb
Public Class PInvoke
<DllImport("vpmsdl32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function loadsession(ByVal vpmname As String) As Long
End Function

<DllImport("vpmsdl32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function setvar(ByVal session As Long, ByVal fieldname As String, ByVal value As String) As Long
End Function

<DllImport("vpmsdl32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function compute(ByVal session As Long, ByVal what As String, ByVal result As String, ByVal result_buffer_size As Long, ByVal message As String, ByVal message_buffer_size As Long, ByVal fieldref As String, ByVal fieldref_buffer_size As Long) As Long
End Function

<DllImport("vpmsdl32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function closesession(ByVal session As Long) As Long
End Function

<DllImport("vpmsdl32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function unloadall() As Long
End Function
End Class
```

and later I call these functions and it works for opening session e.g. `PInvoke.loadsession`. But I don't know how to access to results of `PInvoke.compute` function by similar principle I've used in VBA?

Thank you very much for the response!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried calling compute the way you did in VBA? You should `Dim retcomp As Long` since that is the type returned by compute.

Comment: @Blackwood

Yes, I'm trying to call compute the way I did in VBA. I've already declared `Dim retcomp as Long` , but `retcomp` is just an indicator to give back information if computation is done (1 for succesful, 0 otherwise). I don't know how to extract result of the computation on the way I did it in VBA? Unfortunately, I don't have documentation how to use this in VB.NET, but I'm sure that it is possible. Maybe I need to change declaration of `DLLImport` or something else?